# Cannot close window after refreshing parent window

Tags: javascript

I have a link that opens a new tab, which in turn has a js link that is supposed to update and refresh the opener window and then close the new tab. I am trying to do so by having the link call this function

```
function updatePrev(update){
    window.opener.location = ./prev.html?+update
    window.opener.refresh();
    window.self.close(); //also tried window.close
}
```

It updates the opener window fine, but the current tab does not close. Any suggestions on where I may be messing up?

Comment: Partially dead on my feet right now (so this is probably dead wrong), but JS has a security restriction where JS code cannot close a window that the particular code block in question did not open itself. You might be running into this with your code.

Comment: If I just use <a href="javascript:window.close();" in a link it closes fine though. So I can close a window like this but can't close but by simply moving window.close() to another block and calling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently window.opener.refresh() was preventing the current tab from closing. Without it the tab closes AND the parent (opener) tab gets refreshed

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use "self"? Why not

```
window.close();
```

?

Comment: uncaught TypeError: Object [object Window] has no method 'refresh'

Comment: The opener window refreshes fine though

Comment: Isnt it `window.location.reload()`? In this case `window.opener.location.reload()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `self.close()` According to [Quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html#prob)

> Interestingly, the self.close() command always correctly closes the
>   popup, not the main page.